# AWS Elastic-Beanstalk: ECS task stopped due to: Task failed to start. (nginx-proxy: php-app: )

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to move my Laravel website to Elastic beanstalk using this github script:
https://github.com/peec/laravel-aws

Everything should work out of the box, including RDS db, SQS for queues, elastic cache etc..

I did as requested, but, from some reason, I have this error (even though I have nothing on my website folder, Just make elastic beanstalk work with the docker):
[image: Elastic beanstalk error]

Any idea how can I make it run? or, how should I remove the errors above?

you can find the "Dockerrun.aws.json" file on the github library above, didnt change anything except the AWS Keys on the .ebextensions -> options.config

Thank you!

Eran.